# Embed with Pagination with Buttons (discord_components)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm fairly new to using buttons and i'm trying to do an embed with pagination for my help menu. This below code works as I want it, but after interacting with each of the buttons each time it gives me a "This interaction failed" error under the button.

[image]

```
  if message.content.lower().startswith('.help'):

        embed = discord.Embed(title="test", description="test", color=0x33f6dc)
        embed.set_author(name="test")
        embed.add_field(name="test", value="!test", inline=True)


        embed2 = discord.Embed(title="test2", description="test2", color=0x33f6dc)
        embed2.set_author(name="test2")
        embed2.add_field(name="test2", value="!test2", inline=True)

        pages = 2
        currentpage = 1
        
        page1 = await message.channel.send(embed=embed, components=
        
            [
            
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="▶️", custom_id="next"),
            
            ]
        
                                    )
        while True:
            try:
                interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "next", timeout=300)

                if interaction and currentpage != pages:
                    await page1.edit(embed=embed2, components=
                
                    [
                    
                    Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="◀️", custom_id="back"),
                    
                    ])
                    currentpage += 1

                    interaction2 = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "back")

                    if interaction2 and currentpage > 1:
                        await page1.edit(embed=embed, components=
                    
                        [
                        
                        Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="▶️", custom_id="next"),
                        
                        ])
                        currentpage -= 1
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await page1.delete()
                break
```

Comment: Any errors that you get?

Comment: @ChaoticNebula no errors :( functions as normal, just gives me the three dots ". . . " like its loading, then once the message edits, it puts the back emoji there as it should but underneath it says "This interaction failed".

Comment: It does the same for me. Check for any unhandled interactions.